# How to import data from CSV file into database in flutter

Tags: firebase, csv, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to import data into firebase database from a CSV file in flutter. I want to pick .CSV file from device using file picker and want to upload data into my database. I will retrieve data later from database into my app. How can I achieve that? Is there any way or article that can help me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon the schema of your database and whether your database is local or on a server.

In the first case, if your db is stored on user's device [sqflite package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) to update the database. To read from csv, the [csv package](https://pub.dev/packages/csv) would be helpful.

In the second case, you would have to build an API to communicate the data to server. Sending the entire .csv file would be an easy method.

Comment: I am using Firebase Cloud Firestore as database. so its on a server and can access globally.

Comment: It's easy in that scenario too! You could use csv package to read the file, extract each parameter you want to store in database and use firebase package to update your firestore!